# ¿Cómo interpretar los percentiles en New Relic?

Tags: rendimiento

Al revisar las transacciones en [New Relic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Relic) y ver un gráfico de tiempos de respuestas por transacción web,aparecen filtros por percentiles. ¿Que significan?

[image: Ejemplo de gráfica con tiempos de respuestas]

Answer (score 1):

Los gráficos de líneas de percentiles permiten comparar y analizar datos de tiempo de respuesta para servidores de aplicaciones y navegadores como clasificaciones porcentuales.

- La línea del 99% indica que el 99% de los tiempos de respuesta ocurrieron debajo de esta línea (útil para ayudar a encontrar valores atípicos).
- La línea del 95% indica que el 95% de los tiempos de respuesta ocurrieron debajo de esta línea(útil para establecer un estándar).
- Mediana (donde la mitad de los tiempos de respuesta son más altos que este valor y la mitad son más bajos)
- Promedio (para todas las respuestas en el período de tiempo seleccionado)

Espero que les sirva de ayuda o referencia rápida.